# Calling java script function from different tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, function-call

I have the following code:

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#year li').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    //alert('text is ' + text);
    $.post("B.php", { text: text }, function(return_data, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
$('#result').html(return_data);
});

$.post("C.php", { text: text }, function(return_data, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
$('#subresult').html(return_data);
});
  event.preventDefault() ;
  });

</script>
```

It is written inside the body tag of html. Is it possible to call a js function called initialize() which is written inside the head tag of the html page? if yes how?

### Edits

Code to initialize()

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization">
</script>
<script>
var map;

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8,-187.3),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'geojson';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }
  window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
      var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

geojson is a local file which initially contains nothing but upon the click event contains geojson formatted value of various locations

Comment: Yes: just call `initialize();`

Comment: can you tell me exactly where to call the method? is it before the line event.preventDefault() ;?? because i tried that and it is not working. the function which i am calling is calling a google map api. upon the click event a new geojson file is created and it should call the initialize function and hence reload the map and show the new markers. that is not happenning

Comment: I've added the `jquery` tag for you as you're clearly using jQuery. I'ts important to flag up the libraries you're using so people can help you better.

Comment: Post the code of your `initialize` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to call a js function called initialize() which is written inside the head tag of the html page?

Yes.

> if yes how?

Assuming it's a global function:

```
initialize();
```

All of the script in a page is put in one big namespace. Individual scripts aren't isolated from one another unless you wrap them in scoping functions. So:

```
<head>
<!-- ... -->
<script>
function initialize() {
    alert("initialize!");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
initialize();
</script>
<!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

...works just fine. (And it doesn't matter whether the scripts are inline or refer to external `.js` files.)